# Calling Code From Other Classes

Tags: java, class, if-statement

Hi Im a begginer with Java so no complex code etc

Basically to avoid my code from getting too long i want my user to input a choice and then i have a bunch of for and elese's for what happens if they enter a certain phrase, e.g.

```
if(choice.equals("Fight")) {
   //Grab code from fight.java/fight.class
}
else
{
    if(choice.equals("Train")) {
        //Grab code from train.java/train.class
    }
    else
```

so on and so forth for two other possible inputs. I just need to know how to call external code so it doesn't get too cluttered.

Comment: Read [this official Java tutorial on classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create objects of these classes.

For example:

```
if(choice.equals("Fight")) {
   //Grab code from fight.java/fight.class
   fight f = new fight();
   f.foo(); // A method
}else{
    if(choice.equals("Train")) {
        //Grab code from train.java/train.class
        train t = new train();
        t.foo(); // A method
    }
    //...
}
```

Or you can try static methods like that:

```
public class train{
    public static void foo(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you can use it.

```
if(bool_expression){
    train.foo(); // foo is a static method
}
```

Comment: I embedded this into my code and it gave me the error message "Class Train is public, should be declared in a file named Train.java"

Comment: If your file name is Train.java your class name should be Train

Comment: no My file name is Attributes. java because of an earlier similar error

Comment: If you want to call a static method you should do it like that - ClassName.MethodName()

Comment: I did this
public class Train {
    public static void foo(){
  System.out.println("LAL");
 }
}

Then linked like this

if (choice.equals("Train")) {
      Attributes.foo();
     }

Same error message
my main class is called Attributes and the files are Attributes.java and Attributes.CLASS

Comment: Not Attributes.foo() call Train.foo() because the method named foo is in Train

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the for else structure I would suggest using a switch statement. This will look like:

```
switch(choice){
    case"fight":
        Fight.kickHard();
        break;
    case"train":
        Train.run();
        break;
    default:
        Program.learn();
}
```

Don't forget about the break statements when using a switch. In my example I used static methods from the classes. You would probably be well served by looking further into object oriented design to see if you can come up with a more streamlined answer to your particular problem. The additional classes will need to be imported with an import statement. You will want to look into the shortcut for your IDE to do that for you, but it is a fairly elementary statement e.g import my.package.Train; etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call static methods, it would be as simple doing the following.

```
train.doStuff();
```

If the methods belong to an object you would first have to instantiate an object to access any methods on it.

```
Train train = new Train();
train.doStuff();
```

NOTE: an IDE will automatically link up the classes for you. Otherwise you have to manually import these classes first by adding "import *somepackage.someclass*".

Answer (score 0):

First focus on different things you program can do. Place that code in a method with a name indicating its intent:

```
private static void doWork(){
  System.out.println("Working");
}

private static void play(){
  System.out.println("Playing");
}

private static void sing(){
  System.out.println("Singing");
}
```

Now, you need to bind these to user's phrases (assuming Java 7):

```
   switch(choice){
     case: "work"
       doWork();
       break;
     case: "play"
       play();
       break;
     case: "sing"
       sing();
       break;
     default:
       System.out.println("Unknown choice");
   }
```